# WPF - a timer created by a thread doesn't work

Tags: .net, wpf

Question is about using a timer in each created thread.

I’m writing an application which collects a CPU data from a PC every 30 seconds. It works if I collect data only from 1 PC and using 1 timer, without any thread. Now, I want to collect data from 2 PCs simultaneously. To this end, I decided to use threading where each thread will work for each PC and will have its own timer. So, 2 threads with 2 timers for 2 PCs.   I use System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer to create a timer by each thread. But, the issue is that the created timer doesn't start working (i.e. doesn't call timerTick). 
Hence, if I create a timer without threads, then it works correctly, whereas a thread created timer doesn't work. :(

Maybe the considered solution is not correct and need some changes. Please, help me to understand the problem.

Here is a simple version of the code:

```
void CreateThread()
{
    Thread First = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FirstThreadWork));
    First.Start();
}

private void FirstThreadWork()
{
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer;

    timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timerTick);
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
    timer.Start();
}

private void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Show some data");
}
```

Comment: When you say "collects CPU data every 30 seconds", is that a blocking operation? If not, you will probably not need any multithreading at all.

Comment: There is no need to create a thread just to have it create a timer and exit. Create the timers on the main thread. When the timer's period elapses, the event handler will be called. The `DispatcherTimer` will call on the UI thread, and you don't want to do any blocking operations. Otherwise you'll just block your UI.

Comment: Jim Mischel, sorry, but I couldn't get your proposed idea :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DispatcherTimer` only work if it is created on the UI thread but not on a background thread. If you are not going to manipulate any of the UI elements in your `timerTick` method, then you might want to consider `System.Timers.Timer`

A detalied discussion on all available timers in .net can be found @ [this blog post](http://www.shujaat.net/2010/10/timers-for-net-applications.html)

Sample Code

```
    void StartTimer()
    {
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        timer.Elapsed += timerTick;
        timer.Interval = 30000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();

    }

    private void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Show some data");
    }
```

Comment: Of course, there's not a lot of point in creating a new thread once you take this approach - your `FirstThreadWork` returns as soon as it has created  the timer, which will cause the thread to exit. You may as well just create the timer from whatever thread was calling `CreateThread`. This doesn't really seem like a case where multithreading is necessary in any case.

Comment: @IanGriffiths Agreed, I just copied code from question and updated it to use System.Timers.Timer. I have now updated code to remove creation of extra thread.

Comment: thank you for your help. System.Timers.Timer became a solution for my question